# How to remove logging statements when OpenCV is loaded on android L

Tags: java, android, c++, c, opencv

I am using OpenCV library 2.4.9. To initialise OpenCv library I use a call

```
OpenCvLoaded.initDebug()
```

But this call generates a lot of log statements. I cannot find anything like OpenCvLoaded.initRelease(). Also when I use following code

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {

            }
            break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

I get the error

```
 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myclass}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND }
```

How to remove those log statements. I am building my application on android L. My minimum sdk is 21.

Comment: OpenCV uses java.util.logging.  Your best bet is probably to configure a logging file that your OpenCV app will read during startup:  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html

Comment: As far as your `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit` runtime error look here: [Android L (API 21) Service Intent must be explicit](http://blog.android-develop.com/2014/10/android-l-api-21-javalangillegalargumen.html)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK currently there are two ways to get OpenCV working with Android 5.0 ("Lollipop").

1. The easy way: in the `build.gradle` of your project set `targetSdkVersion 19` (and since your minimum sdk version is 21 you also have to set `minSdkVersion 19` or less).
2. But if you must use Android version 5.0 then the above workaround will not work for you. Instead you can import the [Android OpenCV sources](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.10/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk.zip/download) as a module into your project, setting your main app project to depend on it, and
   adapt the OpenCV file `src/main/java/org/opencv/android/AsyncServiceHelper.java` like follows:

Add the method `createExplicitFromImplicitIntent` ([see the link](http://blog.android-develop.com/2014/10/android-l-api-21-javalangillegalargumen.html) that [FoggyDay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3135317/foggyday) gave above) to the `AsyncServiceHelper` class.

Then adapt the `initOpenCV` method of the `AsyncServiceHelper` class to be:

```
public static boolean initOpenCV(String Version, final Context AppContext,
        final LoaderCallbackInterface Callback)
{
    AsyncServiceHelper helper = new AsyncServiceHelper(Version, AppContext, Callback);
    Intent expIntent = createExplicitFromImplicitIntent(AppContext, new Intent("org.opencv.engine.BIND"));
    if (AppContext.bindService(expIntent,
            helper.mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        AppContext.unbindService(helper.mServiceConnection);
        InstallService(AppContext, Callback);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally do not forget to add the necessary imports:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import java.util.List;
```

As for the log message flooding, another way to stop the output of these lines...

```
02-01 02:25:10.489  29887-29998/com.ABC.opencv_someapp D/CameraBridge? mStretch value: 1.125
02-01 02:25:10.521  29887-29887/com.ABC.opencv_someapp D/JavaCameraView? Preview Frame received. Frame size: 1843200
```

...could be to include the OpenCV sources to your project as sketched above and then remove or comment these lines in the following files:

```
src/main/java/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.java line 408: Log.d(TAG, "mStretch value: " + mScale);
```

and

```
src/main/java/org/opencv/android/JavaCameraView.java line 276: Log.d(TAG, "Preview Frame received. Frame size: " + frame.length);
```